# How to sort an array in descending order?

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have an array:

```
a = [ 0,9,6,12,1]
```

I need a way to sort it in descending order:

```
a = [12,9,6,1,0]
```

For sorting in ascending order I have a Ruby function `a[].to_a.sort`,
I'm looking for a function to sort the array in descending order.

Comment: I'm confused.  I would not be surprised to learn that this question is a duplicate, but not of 'reversing the order of an array'.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You can sort any array `a` (not just those whose elements are numeric) in descending order like this: `a.sort {|x,y| -(x <=> y)}`.  (Aside: where you say, `a[].to_a.sort`, you just want `a.sort`.)

Answer (score 21):

do as below

```
 a = [ 0,9,6,12,1]
 sorted_ary = a.sort_by { |number| -number }
 # or 
 sorted_ary = a.sort.reverse
```

**update**

Another good way to do this :

```
a.sort {|x,y| -(x <=> y)}
```

Comment: Just a note, the latter form is way faster than the former and should be preferred.

Comment: @toro2k I agree with you 200%.. :)

Comment: @rakshit: i have to sort the hex numbers which are in the form of a = [0x1,0x2,0x7]

Comment: @anurag Just give me a moment

Comment: @ArupRakshit: yes sure

Comment: @anurag try this - `a = [0x1,0x2,0x7] ;
p a.sort_by { |num|  -("%d" % num).to_i }`

Comment: @anurag For verification `a.sort_by { |num|  -("%d"%num).to_i }.map { |num| "0x%x"%num }`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: i am getting this output but 0x13and beyond are coming at wrong place.... 0xF0xE0xD0xC0xB0xA0x90x80x70x60x50x40x30x20x10x00x130x120x110x10

Comment: @anurag What is this? :( I don't understand..

Comment: @ArupRakshit: the array elements are a= [0xF,0x1,0xA,0X2,0X8,0X9,0XB]...so i need to sort them

Comment: Sorry to confuse, Arup.  I moved my comment to the question and deleted it here.  Will delete this comment...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
[ 0,9,6,12,1].sort_by do |sort|
  -sort
end
```